# If-Statement in 'Array#each' returns 'true' only on last element

Tags: ruby

I am writing a bot for my discord server, which I want to act as a profanity filter. I read a list of bad words from a text file and store them in an array. Whenever a user sends a message (in a channel the bot is listening to), the bot then checks if that message includes one or more of these bad words. To do that, I use the following code:

```
badWords.each { |badword|
  if content.downcase.include? badword
    ...
  end
}
```

My problem is that the if-statement returns `true` only if the bad word in the content of the message matches the last one in the array. If it matches any other element of the array, it returns `false`.

Is there any functionality of `Array#each` that I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `strip` a badword because it can has `\n` sign in the end.

```
if content.downcase.include?(badword.strip)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to have been the problem.

Comment: This applies `.strip` individually to each badword every time a new `content` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I would break your code up into smaller parts so you can better understand what's going on, and then use one of Ruby's [Enumerable methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) to help make things more concise. Also, let's use Ruby convention of snake_case (`bad_words` instead of `badWords`).

First, let's make sure your `bad_words` array doesn't contain any unwanted characters. It's better to modify the `bad_words` collection a single time rather than iterate over it modifying each element every time.

While we're at it, since our collection will not include duplicates, and since we'll be searching it many times for matching elements, we can increase efficiency greatly by converting the Array to a Set:

```
require 'set'
bad_words = bad_words.map(&:strip).to_set
```

Next let's write a method that just checks if the content contains a bad word. We'll put a question mark at the end of the method name to indicate it returns a boolean value:

```
def profane?(content)
  bad_words.any? { |bad_word| content.include?(bad_word) }
end
```

The `#any?` method returns true if any item passed into the following block returns `true`.

Now your operative code can call `profane?` and take appropriate action:

```
def filter_bad_words(content)
  if profane?(content)
    bot.send_message(event.channel.id, "Sorry #{event.user.name}, this message made my profanity senses tingle!")
    bot.send_message(344559522003812354, "PROFANITY WARNING!!\n user: #{event.user.name}\n message: #{event.content}\n Please check if it is a cause for a warning. Use !?warn to give the user a warning.")
    event.message.delete
    true
  end
end
```

I've made the method return `true` if the content is profane, and it will return `nil` by default if the content is not profane. You can use different return values if you like, and you can take further action based on that response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot in debugging the problem. The solution was what @AlexKojin posted, though.

Comment: OK, but you realize that if the content includes 5 bad_words, you are going to send 5 messages to your user, and then send 5 messages to your log, and then attempt to delete the event.message 5 times. Also, if you have a list of 50 bad_words, you will test each and every one even if the first one is included in `content`. My solution fixes both of those problems.